# When setting the image in a UITableViewCell I get <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am populating a UITableView with Person objects stored in Core Data. Each person has a firstName, lastName, and image. The image is a relationship to a separate Image entity which has a property called data of type Transformable.  This is where I am storing the image associated with each Person.

I am populating the table with:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PersonCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableString *nameString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    if (person.firstName)
    {
        [nameString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",person.firstName]];
    }
    if (person.lastName)
    {
        [nameString appendString:person.lastName];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = nameString;

    UIImage *image = person.image.data;
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

When I run my app, I get the error:

: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.

once for each item in the table or database.

if I comment out the line:

```
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

the error goes away.

Any ideas?  This is the first time I've stored binary data in Core Data, maybe its not transforming right?

This is how I"m storing the image:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.person = [Person personWithImage:image inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
```

and

```
+ (Person *)personWithImage: (UIImage *)image inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Image *newImage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newImage.data = image;

    Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newPerson.image = newImage;

    return newPerson;
}
```

thanks,

Gerry

Comment: is newImage.data your Transformable attribute in the core data?

Comment: yes, newImage is an instance of the Image entity, whose data property has the type Transformable

Comment: i thought that transformable automatically sets the return type to UIImage so that it can be used directly?

Comment: oh, sorry, In my app, I just save the image with NSData. Here I think you can get UIImage directly.

Comment: thanks, the original reason i posted is that when i use the UIImage directly, I get the CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix error. I am wondering if anyone out there has any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured this out by luck.  my uitableview uses images in the cells, and i was putting the full size camera images in there, and of course ran into some memory issues. as soon as I started resizing the images to 960x640, that random CGAffineTransformInvert error went away!

I still don't know why it was happening in the first place, but i guess it doesn't really matter because its gone now.